# PHP mysqli with large result set: Warning: Empty row packet body

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-5.5

TL;DR Why does my PHP script exit with `Warning: Empty row packet body` ?

---

I have a PHP CLI script that migrates product data between 2 MySQL databases, using the mysqli functions. The structure of each database is different, and my script transforms the data to convert from the structure of A to the structure of B.

The basic structure of my code is this:

```
Loop over A.products
    Loop over A.product_variants that match the id from A.products
    Insert into B.products
```

As A.products has over a million rows, to avoid running out of memory I am using MYSQLI_USE_RESULT instead of MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT.

I tried running a query to get A.product_variants while I am looping over the A.products result set, and I got this error:  Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

To solve this, I now fetch A.products using one connection, and A.product_variants using a separate connection. The insert uses a third connection to database B.

This now works successfully until it reaches around row 1030 in A.products. It does not always stop at the same row, but close. Then I get this error and the loop exits:

```
Warning: Empty row packet body in script.php line 500
```

Which is the $mysqli->fetch_object() line:

```
while ($product = $res_products->fetch_object())
```

- PHP version: 5.5.29
- Client API library version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev
- MySQL Server: 5.5

**What causes this error? How can I fix it?**

Comment: why two loops? can't you use an `insert into ... select from` single query?

Comment: I need to make changes to the data between the select and insert (json encode some fields, regex replace other fields) that are too complex to do in SQL.